# Switch between layouts in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm working in a project with lots of files and switching between different tasks. And having a lot of files open at once clog the tabs in the panes (and my brain). So therefore I would like to be able to switch out all my panes/views much like switching workspace in Linux. And when I switch back it remembers the files/views/tabs.

In short: ability to toggle between this:

```
          Layout 1                              Layout 2
----------------------------          ----------------------------
|            |             |          |            |             |
| file a     | file a2     |          | file b     |  file b2    |
| (+3 tabs)  |             |          |            |             |
|            |             |          |            |             |
|            |             |          |            |             |
|            |-------------|          |            |             |
|            | file a3     |          |            |             |
|            |             |          |            |             |
----------------------------          ----------------------------
```

Does Sublime 3 has this functionality or is there a package that can help with this?

Comment: You can easily switch to the layouts you're describing using **set_layout** command, but I think you'll have to make a plugin if you want to implement *switch back* and *files/views/tabs* remembering, as set_layout command seems to move all files to first group. Don't know if there are plugins that do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is detail explenation for layout creating in sublime text : [example](http://nikolaloncar.com/sublime-text-layout-inside-out-with-examples/)

My suggestion is to create those two layouts and put key shortcut for both.

Install [chain of command](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command) plugin. Create key shortcut for mulitple commands :

```
1. set layout 2
2. move focus to group 1
3. open "file b" by name [plugin]
4. move focus to group 2
5. open "file b2" by name [plugin]
```

Do same thing for layout 1 scenario. Here is example how to create plugin for opening file by name [how-to-open-file-using-only-keyboard-in-sublime-text](https://superuser.com/questions/467693/how-to-open-file-using-only-keyboard-in-sublime-text) . You need to modify some part of that plugin because it use input dialog.